# Is performance worse routing between two vlans on one interface than routing between two NICs with no vlans?

Tags: vlan, nat, performance

I have a Linux router with one interface that is connected to a switch in port 2.

Port 2 on the switch is a member of vlan2(ISP) and vlan3 (office devices).

My router is currently routing between these two vlans for everything to access the internet.

I suspect the network card is becoming faulty and I will just upgrade to a new one.

In which case, is it better if I buy a network card with two ports for Natting between them and get rid of the vlans?

Or does it make little to no performance difference routing between two vlans and just keep one card with one port?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there's no performance difference in routing through a single interface or through multiple interfaces, unless there's a bottleneck in the hardware.

Up to gigabit, a software router should be OK (assuming it's adequately powered). However, I'd use a dual-port NIC just for the sake of a clean division between LAN and WAN.